# Structuring a class

Tags: java

I have a couple methods that need to run sequentially. They all live in the same class. Is it better to structure them like this?

```
public class Test{

    public Test(){
        foo1();
    }

    private void foo1(){
        //do stuff
        foo2();
    }

    private void foo2(){
        //do stuff
        foo3();
    }

    private void foo3(){
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Or this.

```
public class Test{

    public Test(){
        doFoo();
    }

    private void doFoo(){
        foo1();
        foo2();
        foo3();
    }
    private void foo1(){
        //do stuff
    }

    private void foo2(){
        //do stuff
    }

    private void foo3(){
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Which way would be more clear? I'm leaning towards the second example, but i'm not sure if having a method that only calls other methods is best practice.

Comment: The first way is more unclear, since you're doing daisy-chaining.

Comment: [Why do you make an additional method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) to invoke foo1, foo2 and foo3 ? Invoke them directly in your constructor.

Comment: I prefer the second example as well. It is easier to follow the flow.

Comment: *I'm not sure if having a method that only calls other methods is best practice.* Why? If you were writing the code without thinking about this, you would first write the 3 pieces of code inside the method, then realise they do independent stuff, thus you extract them into 3 private methods.

Comment: Are these methods being reused independently at all? It may be a good idea to keep them separate, unless foo2 and foo3 are always called together in which case you may as well just make it foo23

Comment: The ultimate answer is the first sentence of Robert's answer: we don't have enough information to provide a specific answer. If it's a natural pipeline, they should be separate methods. If it's not, then it still depends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the operations. If operation foo2 is part of what foo1 does, then you should call foo2 from foo1.

If foo1 and foo2 are unrelated and only part of the foo operation, then call these two from foo.

It depends on the semantics of the methods which call hierarchy is clearer and therefore easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The second example is better for multiple reasons.

First, you can write unit tests to test `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`. With the first method you can only do a unit test for `foo1`.

Second, the second solution is better if in the future you have to change the order of your calls.

Comment: I don't understand your argument about testing. Why would you only be able to test `foo1` in the first case?

Comment: @Manu You can make a test for `foo2`, but `foo2` is already tested with `foo1`. And in fact, if `foo3` crash, then `foo1` and `foo2` will crash too. So that's not that you can't test `foo2` and `foo3`, but results may be hard to deal with.

Comment: The correct approach for testing each method is to stub/mock the nested methods. That said, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with a unit test at the `foo1` level that indirectly tests `foo2` and `foo3`, although it's a hybrid unit/integration test. It depends on method visibility and complexity at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on what these methods do.

If they are really three steps that need to be done in sequence then version 2 is better.

But if they are "nested" steps where `foo2` is part of what needs to be done in `foo1` then version 1 is better.

Example for the second case:  `writeJavaBeanToFile` transforms the bean to a Map, then calls `writeJavaMapToFile` which transforms the Map to a String and calls `writeStringToFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see both of the methods have their pros and cons. As far as readability goes the second example is much easier to follow. There is one example where the first one might be useful though.

```
public class Test{

    public Test(){
        foo1();
    }

    private int foo1(){
        //do stuff
        if(something went wrong) return -1;
        foo2();
        return 0;
    }

    private int foo2(){
        //do stuff
        if(something went wrong) return -1;
        foo3();
        return 0;
    }

    private int foo3(){
        //do stuff
        if(something went wrong) return -1;
        return 0;
    } 

}
```

Depending on wheter you want to execute `foo3` regardless whether or not an error occurs the second example would be better. If you only want to execute `foo3` if `foo2` is successful the first method might be useful.

Comment: You should add `return` in front of `foo2()` and `foo3()`

Answer (score 0):

You should follow second method which is also a pattern - facade pattern. You basically want to do 3 operations in sequence and your invocation is made much simpler if you map these 3 to 1 method. This is what facade pattern also does - easing up the invocation interface.